# Find the value of this expression $x^6+y^3x^3+y^6$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can you help me with this exercise:

> For $x, y \in \mathbb R$, given $x^2+yx+y^2=4$ and $x^4+x^2y^2+y^4=8$, calculate $$x^6+y^3x^3+y^6$$

Thanks.

Comment: @Cornman, definitely not, but that doesn't matter.

Comment: x,y are from R and there is no z

Comment: @Ennar I see, since the first equation has no integer solutions.

Comment: The whole exercise is just to use $a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$ enough times. And $a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$ would help as well.

Comment: @Ennar, I tried that but I couldn't find the answer,

Comment: You are new to MSE, so please read [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). As it is now, your question is likely to be closed soon. You have to show some input on your own, otherwise people are not likely to help.

Comment: the information you are given is enough to (easily) find $x+y$ and $xy.$ Mostly because the polynomial $x^4 + x^2 y^2 + y^4$ factors nicely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is kind of hard to notice, but:

$$(x^2+y^2)^2=x^4+y^4+2x^2y^2\rightarrow (x^2+y^2)^2-x^2y^2=x^4+x^2y^2+y^4=8$$
$$(x^3+y^3)^2=x^6+y^6+2x^3y^3\rightarrow (x^3+y^3)^2-x^3y^3=x^6+y^3x^3+y^6=\text{WHAT WE ARE TRYING TO SOLVE FOR}$$

Thus, we need to find $x^3y^3$ and $x^3+y^3$. First, the left-hand side fo the first equation can be factored using $a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$:

$$(x^2+y^2+xy)(x^2+y^2-xy)=8$$

It is given that $x^2+y^2+xy=4$:

$$4(x^2+y^2-xy)=8\rightarrow x^2+y^2-xy=2$$

Add this equation by $x^2+y^2+xy=4$:

$$2x^2+2y^2=6\rightarrow x^2+y^2=3$$

Subtract $x^2+y^2+xy=4$ by $x^2+y^2-xy=2$:

$$2xy=2\rightarrow xy=1\rightarrow x^3y^3=1$$

Now, we just need to find $x^3+y^3$. To do this, add $xy=1$ to $x^2+y^2+xy=4$:

$$x^2+y^2+2xy=(x+y)^2=5\rightarrow x+y=\pm \sqrt 5$$

Multiply by $x^2+y^2-xy=2$:

$$(x+y)(x^2+y^2-xy)=x^3+y^3=\pm 2\sqrt 5$$

Finally, we have:

$$x^6+y^3x^3+y^6=(x^3+y^3)^2-x^3y^3=(\pm 2\sqrt 5)^2-1=20-1=19$$

Comment: And why $x+y\neq - \sqrt 5$? Since $x^4+y^4 = 7$, I'd just calculate $(x^4+y^4)(x^2+y^2) = x^6+y^6+x^2y^2(x^2+y^2)$

Comment: x+y = sqrt(5) verify also this equation x^2+x*y+y^2=4

Comment: @ENIMADADDEHC, what about it? There are precisely four solutions to the system $(x+y)^2=5$, $x^2+xy+y^2=4$, two of which give $x+y=\sqrt 5$ and two give $x+y=-\sqrt 5$.

Comment: Your remark is on point,using (x^4+y^4)(x^2+y^2) still the best solution to avoid the cases distinctions .

Comment: @Ennar Technically, $x+y=\pm\sqrt 5$, but I square it at the end, so it cancels out and in the end, it doesn't matter. A common technique in problems where they tell you to find the value of some expression is that you assume that the expression you are trying to find only has one possible value, so if there are multiple cases like $x+y=\sqrt 5$ or $-\sqrt 5$, you just try to find the value of the expression for one of the cases since the value will be the same across both cases. This is not a mathematical proof, but it is a valid way to find the answer for many competition problems.